# Visual Studio 2008 underlining non-error code in red

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2008, syntax-error, underline

I have a large C# project in Visual Studio 2008, and nearly half my project is underlined in red errors; most of them are `"Undeclared element";`. The project compiles, builds, debugs, and runs fine, no errors.

I can also type a legitimate error, and it doesn't underline the error. For instance if I write `strong.Format()` instead of `string.Format`, it doesn't underline strong? But, it will underline the `Format`, in `string.Format` and tell me `undeclared element`; it makes no sense.

Similar to question:

- [Visual Studio 2010 Improperly underlining code/comments with red error line when there is no error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9729621/visual-studio-2010-improperly-underlining-code-comments-with-red-error-line-when)

But he never got an answer, and this is VS 2008 and C# instead of VS 2010 and C++

Comment: Are you running any plug-ins like ReSharper etc.?

Comment: Same problem on both installs, one on my desktop, one my laptop; laptop is running a bunch of extensions (but not resharper) and desktop is not running any, its a clean install.

Comment: Using the same codebase or with any project you create? It's possible that something in your code could be triggering an issue with the code highlighting.

Comment: same problem tends to happen whenever we get more than about 20 projects in one solution; as long as the number of projects is less than 15 or 20, everything works fine; but on our mega solutions (about 4) this is a consistent issue.

Comment: Sounds like a Visual Studio limitation. The best approach, IMO, would be to create a number of solutions that contain related projects so that you don't have to have so many projects loaded into a single solution.

Comment: Occasionally see the same problem on my own code.  Its ignorable for the most part.  I also notice that If I'm on the page long enough it will frequently fix itself.  Not always though, and the length of time varies due to some factor I haven't bothered looking for. I just accept it as a bit of weirdness and go on with my life =D

Comment: I have the same problem here! It incorrectly underlines simple C code in a solution with a single project with less than 20 files of source code. So maybe its not a limit on number of projects or files etc. I have noticed that in my case it happens after a reinstall of Windows/VS (happened one before with a project having only 2 source files after a Windows/VS reinstall). The issue is present even if I reinstall it in same directories, but all incorrect underlining is related only to library functions and types. But it still underlines actual errors, like if I type `Strong` instead of `String`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Generally you might experience this problem when you have tools like ReSharper running.

They generally rely on cached information and dll's present in your bin directory, if you have a complex project and it gets into a state where there are unexpected dll's present or complex build scripts which to some magic to move dll's around etc.

What I would recommend, is to do a clean using VS clean solution command, and [clear ReSharper](http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/webhelp/Reference__Options__Environment__General.html) or any other code analysis tools cache.

If that doesn't work you could go [more indepth](http://weblogs.asp.net/psheriff/archive/2011/11/08/clean-up-after-visual-studio.aspx)

Comment: Perfect, I've had one solution, bugged for over a year now, on a vanilla 2008 install, and the in depth options are the only thing that fixed it!!!

Answer (score 0):

I have had this problem several times, both with Visual Studio by itself and with Resharper.  In both cases I was able to fix the problem by blowing away the whole project and re-checking it out from version control.  Assuming you aren't using version control, this basically means blowing away all the generated files including .obj, .exe, .dll. and .suo files.  Also delete the Resharper directories, assuming you use Resharper.

(I'm assuming all executable files in your source tree are generated.  Obviously you don't want to delete them if they are not generated.)

Answer (score -2):

I had the same issue, and in my case it was mostly related to library functions and types defined in libraries. This one fixed it for me:

Open command line parameters. You can use following to reach there:

`Project` > `*ProjectName* Properties` > `Configuration Properties` > `Linker` > `Command Line`

In the Additional Options box at the bottom add
`/I "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\include"`

You will of course need the correct path where Visual Studio is installed. Add as many paths as you need, each path with a separate `/I`

Bingo! I hope it works for you too. :)

Also, if you create any new Project/Solution then you won't need to add this one to your compiler options. It just works fine with new projects, or at least this is the case for me. Typical Microsoft stuff... :S

Comment: Upvoted your comment, and this solution actually did work great for my C++ code, but the original question was about my C#/.NET code. Really wish there was a way to fix this for .NET